# Special characters from STRINGTABLE not displayed correctly if built on differnt machine?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, character-encoding, special-characters

I have to maintain a small C++ / VS2015 project in my department which only checks the installed .NET Framework of a machine and prompts the user if the current version is not installed. This small application is localized by a file called Language.rc which contains some STRINGTABLES with the corresponding texts.
All this works fine if the program is compiled on my machine, but if the same code is compiled on our build machines then the special characters like for example the German ÄÖÜ are missing.
Unfortunately I'm not a c++ person and I have no clue what is wrong. I already searched the web but cannot find a hint on what might be the problem.

Does anybody have an idea what could be different on the build machines compared to my machine that causes the different characters?

UPDATE:

So after my TFS expert has analysed the problem on the build machines we were able to identify the culprit:

As I said before the application that was causing the problem is only a small tool. Our automatic build contains a lot more solutions and projects. One part of the automatic build is a script that sets the version numbers of all kinds of files to the same value. This is apparently also done for so called RC files. As far as I understand there are different kinds of RC files in C++ (and also in Delpi) which actually hold version numbers. The RC file in my case only has texts and translations but is opened and also saved even though it does not have a version number.
Unfortunately this operation also explicitly sets the encoding of the file to some old IBMxyz encoding (maybe for the Delphi RC files?). This is the actual operations where the special characters get lost... So the solution to my problem is not within the original encoding of the file but somewhere in the build process. 
As a temporary fix we changed the .rc file to an .rc2 file - this way the project still compiles but the build does no longer modify it.

I've had enough fun for today...

Answer (score 0):

Windows has two ways of handling text. These are known as "Unicode" (really UTF-16) and "ANSI" (which isn't related to the ANSI standards organization, and describes **any** 8 bit superset of ASCII).

Your problem is clearly a case of "ANSI" disease. ASCII does not contain "Ä", some supersets of ASCII do, but not all supersets do. Different machines using different supersets will cause different results.

The "simple" fix is to prefix an L to the string in the .rc file: `L"zum Beispiel"`, and then save this .rc file as Unicode (UTF-16). While newer versions of Windows contain more UTF-16 characters, this never affects existing characters, and Ä has been part of every Unicode version. (Even € works everywhere - I think that was added in Windows 2000)

Comment: OK still no luck.
First I prefixed my strings in the RC file with L still the executables from the build servers are lacking the special characters.
Second I changed the file encoding to UTF-8 using NotePad++ (which for wahtever reason doesn ot offer UTF-16). But as it turns out the ressource compiler does not like UTF-8 and calims the file would not exist.
Then I tried to save the RC file with a different encoding by using VS's 'Advanced Save Options...' dialog setting the Encoding to 'Unicode - Codepage 1200' which should equal UTF-16 as far as I understood. This did not help either :-/

Comment: Notepad++ has an explicit Encoding menu, it's not merged in the "Save as" dialog. With Visual Studio the Unicode save option indeed should work - but some machines still mutilate the Ä ?

Comment: I've done some more research on the build machines and it turns out that there is something wrong with the way our TFS gets the files for the build. While the file is in the correct encoding when it is retrieved from TFS via Visual Studio, it is not in the correct encoding when TFS retrieves it for the automatic build.